# ANOVA uncertainty

Tags: anova, feature-selection

If I have 10 classification accuracies for 3 different parameter, and I perform an ANOVA test  which yields $F=1.19$ and $\text{Prob>F}$ $0.3201$. The parameter value indicates the number of features. Does that mean none of the 3 parameter values yields a significantly different result than the other?

More importantly, how can I justify choosing one parameter value over the other? The thing is with 3 features I get an accuracy of 96%, while with 2 and 4 features I get 92% and 88% respectively. Hence, I want to justify using 3 features instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

(I assume the models with fewer features are nested in the models with more features, otherwise these sorts of hypothesis tests won't work)

Classification accuracy is a kind of count proportion.

You would not normally use ANOVA on count proportions.

Logistic regression is one common choice for comparison binomial proportions.

If the classification accuracy differs by category within the larger model (but were constant within it), then the overall success counts would be a sum of binomials, one for each category (but they could be separately modelled if the data were available that way).

(Alternatively, quasi-binomial models may suffice to capture the variance)

---

Another possibility would be to use Welch-Satterthwaite style adjustment to degrees of freedom to deal with the heteroskedasticity.